# React Native : Store data like an array of object with redux persist

Tags: arrays, react-native, object, react-redux, asyncstorage

I want to store a data Like an array of object by using redux persist... the storage engine that I use is Asyncstorage and when I want to persist data like this

boutiquepanie:[...state.boutiquepanie , action.value]

I get this error :

Invalid attempt to spread non iterable instance. In order to be iterable , non array object must have a symbol.iterator method.

I think that the problem is the data format because state.boutiquepanie is an object

And when I try this
boutiquepanier:action.value the data is persist

Comment: what is the default or initial value you have for `boutiquepanie` ?

Comment: boutiquepanie = await asyncstorage.getitem(panier)  and the key panier is defined on the persistconfig data of my reducrer like this : persistconfig{ key:panier ,storage: asyncstorage}